# How To Remove/hide some specific categories from two different categories widget from sidebar

Tags: wp-query, categories, sidebar

I have two categories sidebar widgets with different topics on my site. I want to hide some specific categories from each of the widgets. Is there any way to do so?

Suppose I have total Categories like Health, Life, Fashion, and Sports.
Now I have two category widgets, Widget1 and Widget2.
I want Health and life categories in Widget1( but hide the other two from this widget) and Fashion and Sports in widget2.

I searched everywhere on the internet and found some codes but they are working if there is only a single category widget on the site.
Please Help me. This question is totally new and does not match the previous ones.